# Scaling html page for mobile

Tags: html

I want to make my html page scale with the mobile screen it is opened on. This is my code I have. I have added the initial scale 1 line but it doesn't seem to work. I want the images the input box and the radio button to scale with the width and height of the device the page is opened on. I am using html/css and bootstrap to make the page and some JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <img class="img-responsive" src="corendonwifi.png" alt="Chania" width="460" align="middle" height="345"> 
    <script>
      function myFunc() {
        var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
        var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');

        checker.onchange = function(){
          if(this.checked){
            sendbtn.disabled = false;
          } else {
            sendbtn.disabled = true;
          }
        }
      }
    </script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Corendon WI-FI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <style type="text/css">
      H1 { text-align: center }
      .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
      }
      body {
        position: fixed;
        top: 20%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -35%);
      }
      input, textarea {
        max-width:100%
      };
      img {
        max-width: 100%
      };
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="myFunc();">
    <div class="bs-example">
      <div class="bs-example">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputticketnummer">Ticketnummer</label> 
            <input type="ticketnummer" class="form-control" id="inputticketnummer" maxlength="20" placeholder="ticketnummer" size=""  required>
          </div>
          <input type="checkbox"  id="checkme"/> Ik heb de <a href="agreements" class="button">voorwaarden</a> gelezen </label>
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="btn btn-primary" class="btn-xs" disabled="disabled" id="sendNewSms" value=" ga door " />
        </form></div></form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get proper page scaling using Bootstrap, you must set up a grid system for the page. Right now, Bootstrap can't tie into anything and therefore not scale it.

Have a look at the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code like the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>

   <script>
    function myFunc() {
    var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
    var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');

    checker.onchange = function(){
   if(this.checked){
       sendbtn.disabled = false;
   } else {
       sendbtn.disabled = true;
   }
   }
   }
   </script>

   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Corendon WI-FI</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet"        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
   <style type="text/css">
H1 { text-align: center }
.bs-example{
    margin: 20px;
     }
   /*body{
     position: fixed;
     top: 20%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -35%);
   }*/
   input, textarea {
     max-width:100%;
   }
   img {
     max-width: 100%;
   }

   </style>
   </head>
   <body onload="myFunc();">





   <div class="container">

       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
               <img class="img-responsive" src="corendonwifi.png" alt="Chania" width="460" align="middle" height="345"> 
    </div><!--col-sm-12-->
</div><!-- row -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" onload="myFunc();"></div>
</div><!-- row -->


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 bs-example">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usr">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
            </div>
        </div><!-- col-sm-12 -->

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>
            </div>
        </div><!-- col-sm-12 -->

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="btn btn-primary" class="btn-xs" disabled="disabled" id="sendNewSms" value=" ga door " />
            </div>
        </div><!-- col-sm-12 -->


    </div><!-- col-sm-12 bs-example -->
</div><!-- row -->


   </div><!-- container -->




   </body>
   </html>
```

Firstly, while using bootstrap always use bootstrap classes. Secondly, dont use transform property in your css and position fixed in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup has several errors.
You can use the [bootstrap classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to address this issue, but also can become free and use them as needed.

Repalce your CSS code for that:

```
.form{
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
img{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.row{
    margin-bottom:10px
}
```

And replace your markup, for that:

```
<body onload="myFunc();">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="row">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="corendonwifi.png" alt="Chania" width="460" align="middle" height="345"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="form">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="inputticketnummer">Ticketnummer</label> 
                <input type="ticketnummer" class="form-control" id="inputticketnummer" maxlength="20" placeholder="ticketnummer" size=""  required> 
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="checkbox"  id="checkme"/> Ik heb de <a href="agreements" class="button">voorwaarden</a> gelezen
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="btn btn-primary" class="btn-xs" disabled="disabled" id="sendNewSms" value=" ga door " />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

See my fiddle [HERE!](http://jsfiddle.net/dag053eq/)